# How to structure my classes in Java project

Tags: java, design-patterns, model

Recently I began an adventure with JAVA. I am looking for a guidance on design patterns and overall architecture of JAVA project.

I'm working on a small application project as university assignment. It's a typical learning-by-doing project. The app has GUI made up of Swing elements and few additional classes.

The problem that I face is realted with lack of idea of how to tie it all together. Specifically I face following problems:

***Problem 1***

Login problem - I have custom **User** class. I keep the current_user as property of main **JFrame**.

During GUI loading - I would like to check if the user is signed in. Also - on specific actions - I would like to sign out user.

Currently I solve both problems by going all the way to `mainFrame.current_user` property. But I feel that's bad approach. As there can only be one user in the application - there should be a way of defining globally visible methods like `current_user`, `user_signed_in()` or `sign_out(current_user)` without calling JFrame. Is my feeling correct?

***Problem 2***

During initialization of GUI I am creating a **JTable** that is displaying data downloaded from web with custom **WebRequest** class. **JTable** data is kept in `Object data[][]` a  property of table model extending **AbstractTableModel**. Right now I am building the data model when the application starts - meaning calling a WebRequest, initializing Table and it's model.

Right now I would like to change this behavior. I would like to display empty JTable when the application starts - and call the WebRequest only by clicking **JMenuItem** refresh button.

How to approach it? At the moment my only idea is to have **JTable** data model and call a one of it's methods - something like `refresh()`. This method should call **WebRequest** and update **JTable**. But for this I have to get from **JMenuItem** to **JTable** that is in completely different place.

What can be better approach here? Again - there can be only one Data model to call in the app - so maybe a similliar problem to Problem 1?

---

Also if you know a good reading on design patters, or good open source repos to study - I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem I would suggest an extre class named "Authentication". This class should have a User. The class can also have following methods: signOut(), signIn(String username, String password),...

For the check I should do the following:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    if(currentUser != null){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT** Java uses a naming convention: use mixedCase, no underscores.

For the second problem:

I would suggest to search for the Observer pattern for your refresh idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for some guidance, I would suggest you have a look at the [Oracle tutorial on Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) and give special attention to the [Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Model use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) parts of it as it will answer your second problem.

As for the first one, I would suggest you don't actually put your `current_user` element *in* the JFrame.

The Model-View-Controler or Model-View-Presenter are good starting point as design-patterns here.